# Can I have persistent sessions for VS Code Remote Development?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code offers a really nice way to do remote development over SSH with its Remote Development extension. Does this extension and its terminal has support for permanent sessions that would survive disconnects?

- You can achieve this by running UNIX `screen` within Visual Studio Code terminal
- However, Visual Studio Code itself installs its remote agent, so maybe this remote agent offers similar functionality built-in, leading to easier user experience (no need to hassle with `screen`)

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly is meant by "surviving disconnects"?

Comment: The underlying SSH session disconnects and takes down Visual Studio Code terminal with it

Comment: ?? so you just want a terminal to not close after an SSH connection it's being sued for is ended?

Comment: The question is relevant for those people who use `screen` and have similar workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

> Does this extension and its terminal has support for permanent sessions that would survive disconnects?

No, it seems that, currently, the [«Remote - SSH» Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) does not have such a feature.

## Straightforward solution

It seems to be a known «Remote - SSH» Visual Studio Code extension issue:

- GitHub issue: [Persistent SSH session · Issue #3096 · microsoft/vscode-remote-release · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3096).

Roughly speaking, the solution is:

1. To communicate with the maintainers (for example, by posting comments on the GitHub issue).
2. If applicable, to wait for a next «Remote - SSH» Visual Studio Code extension release with the resolved issue.